# Using composition vs embedding in yaml model structs

Tags: go, yaml

I have the following `yaml` file

```yaml
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: mynamespace
```

And using the following construct to unmarshal it

```golang
type hr struct {
    APIVersion string `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Kind       string `yaml:"kind"`
    Metadata   `yaml:"metadata"`
}

type Metadata struct {
    Name      string `yaml:"name"`
    Namespace string `yaml:"namespace"`
}
```

My question is whether there is a practical difference in using embedding vs composision in the `hr` struct, i.e instead if declaring it as above, providing a name in the `Metadata` field, as in

```golang
type hr struct {
    APIVersion string   `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    Kind       string   `yaml:"kind"`
    MD         Metadata `yaml:"metadata"`
}
```

Is any of the two approaches preferred over the other when it comes to `yaml` unmarshalling?

(both methods seem to be working fine btw in the actual unmarshalling)

Comment: Note that embedding is composition, an embedded field is still just a field. Embedding is useful if you want the embedded type's methods and/or fields to be directly accessible through an instance of the embedding type. That's it. That's the use case.